# What are the differences between LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemons?

Tags: launchd, startup

On macOS 10.12.5, I only see LaunchAgents in the Users Library directory. Are the agents only invoked if a user is logged in?

- /Library/LaunchAgents/
- /Library/LaunchDaemons/
- /System/Library/LaunchAgents/
- /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/
- /User/*username*/Library/LaunchAgents/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, `LaunchAgents` are only invoked when the user logs into a graphical session.

`LaunchDaemons` are typically launched when the system boots and are run outside of a specific user session.

The [lauchctl manual page](https://ss64.com/osx/launchctl.html) lists these folders with short descriptions:

> ### Files
>
> - `~/Library/LaunchAgents` Per-user agents provided by the user.
> - `/Library/LaunchAgents` Per-user agents provided by the administrator.
> - `/Library/LaunchDaemons` System-wide daemons provided by the administrator.
> - `/System/Library/LaunchAgents` Per-user agents provided by Mac OS X.
> - `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` System-wide daemons provided by Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks Graham! Would you happen to know which user runs `/Library/LaunchAgents` launch agents?

Comment: Each user runs their own instance of the LaunchAgents entries. They launch when the user logs in.